# Test strings for all alphabet characters or all integers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string which is of format ABC1234567

```
var value = "ABC1234567"  
var first3Letters = value.substring(0,3);  // ABC   
var next7Letters = value.substring(3,7);   //1234567`
```

Now I want to validate whether variable ***first3Letters*** contains only alphabets, and variable ***next7letters*** contains only integers.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
if ( /^[a-z]+$/i.test (first3Letters ) ) {
    // It's good.
}

if ( /^\d+$/.test (next7Letters) ) {
    // It's good.
}
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/peBPq/1/)

---

**Regex explained:**

1. `^` specifies the beginning of the string.
2. `&` specifies the end of the string.
3. `[a-z]` is any word character (A, B, C, etc., but NOT numbers or the the underscore -- which `\w` would allow).
4. `\d` is any number character (0, 1, 2, etc.)
5. `+` means one or more of the previous.
6. The `i` at the end (`i.test`) tells JS to run a case-insensitive search.

So the regexes are essentially saying, "From the beginning to the end, are there nothing but 1 or more (word or number) characters."

See also: [Regular expressions tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks Brock .. it worked .. A small favor can you explain these regex

Comment: I think '\w' in the first regex will match numbers as well as letters

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = "ABC1234567"  

alert("Matches: "+ value.test(/^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{7}$/));
```

Comment: The syntax of `test()` is wrong; the code will throw an exception.  Also `\w` allows digits too.  IE, `"6661234567"` and `"___1234567"` would both pass that regex.

Comment: i fixed \w and \d. test() is not wrong though try it in jsfiddle.net

Comment: If you have a fiddle, link to it.  That `test()` syntax will not work in **any** standard browser.  You'll get something like `"value.test is not a function"`.

Answer (score 0):

For the second you can use the `isNaN` method, it'll take a string representation of a number, and return as expected, i.e. `var x = 2; var y = "2"`, and both return the same from `isNaN()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var test    =   'AAAA1122';
    chr =   test.split(/\d/i);
    integer =   test.split(/\D/i);

    alert("+++++++chr+++++"+chr[0]+"++++++++++++");
    alert("++++++int++++++"+integer[0]+"++++++++++++");
```